# I want to change opacity from 0 to 1 of the element when it's scrolled up to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter-bootstrap on my page and I have a video background. It looks like this https://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/41/ . When user scrolls down, the black section starts to appear and first its opacity is set to 0, but when user continue scrolling - it changes to 1 when he reach end of this section. I want to change that, so the section will have the opacity set to 1 when it fully appears on the screen, so the user will see the black background of this component when it's fully visible on the page.
So this is not good: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOEKo.png , but something like this one is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qqMb.jpg 
I tried to go with:

```
$("#black").css("opacity",$("body").scrollTop()/1000);
```

but it didn't work. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Do you have this code inside of an event listener?

Comment: When is this happening?  Inside an onscroll event bind?

Comment: @CarlEdwards yes I do, I put it in `$(window).scroll(function(){`, and it partially works - the div gets darker when user scrolls and is completely black when user reaches end of it, and I want to make it black when it is on top of the page

Comment: How about `1-$("body").scrollTop()/1000`?

Comment: @JohnBupit it didn't work http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/43/ , it's black at the very beginning of scrolling, but when it goes lower its opacity is going closer to 0.... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that changes the opacity as the user scrolls down, starting from opacity 0 at the top of the document, and becoming opacity 1 when they reach the element:

```
$("#black").css("opacity",1 -($("#black").offset().top - $("body").scrollTop()) / $("#black").offset().top);
```

It works by comparing the black element's position on the page against the current scroll value. For additional performance, you could cache the jQuery selectors and the call to `.offset`.

---

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/45/

Comment: Yes, that worked, that's exactly what I wanted, it works pretty smooth :) Thank you very much!

Comment: btw, one more question - because I don't exactly understand what do you mean by caching the jquery selectors... could you explain me that? or give me some example maybe? Thanks!

Comment: @randomuser1 [An article](http://ttmm.io/tech/selector-caching-jquery/) and [a StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743326/why-cache-jquery-objects) on selector caching

Answer (score 1):

How about checking the scrollTop against the height of the video container?  Something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".move").toggle($(this).scrollTop() === 0);
    var videoHeight = $('.video-container2 video').height();
    var scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
    var opacity = scrollTop >= videoHeight ? 1 : 0;
    $("#black").css("opacity",opacity);
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: so that's how it looks now http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/44/ , it partially works, but is there a way of making it seamless and with smooth transition, instead of changing it just from 0 to 1?

Comment: how about adding a css opacity transition on #black?  something like #black { transition: opacity .7s }

Comment: yeah, that's a dirty hack :) It won't solve the issue unfortunately - I just want to make it so that when the div is visible at 1/4 of the screen it's opacity is set to 0.25, and when it's fully visible then the opacity is 1

Comment: ah, I see; guess I misunderstood the question...I think TomSlick's answer will be what you want then.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the `scrollTop` of body by the height of the video to get the transition you're looking for

```
var videoHeight = $('.video-container2 video').height();
var scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
var opacity = scrollTop / videoHeight;
$("#black").css("opacity", opacity);
```