# jQuery's .each slower on Safari than Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large HTML table (1,000-1,500 rows, 40 cols wide).  I have a few input and select boxes so users can filter rows.  The relevant javascript/jquery (note: not entire code base is pasted in as it is not the bottleneck) attached to it looks like:

```
function autoRank() {
    // auto number
    rank = 0;
    $("#myTablePlayers .playerData").each(function() {
        if ($(this).css("display") != "none") {
            rank++;
            $(this).find('td').eq(colRank).text(rank);
        }
    });
}

var teamCols = $(),
    GPCols = $(),
    posCols = $(),
    ageCols = $();

$("#myTablePlayers .playerData").each(function() {
  var columns = $(this).find('td');
  teamCols = teamCols.add($(".colTeam", this));
  GPCols = GPCols.add(columns.eq(colGP));
  posCols = posCols.add(columns.eq(colPos));
  ageCols = ageCols.add(columns.eq(colAge))
});

function filterTable() {
    // Need some error checking on input not number
    minGP = $("#mingp").val()
    teams = $("#teamFilter").val().toUpperCase()
    position = $("#position").val()
    age = $("#age").val()

    $("#myTablePlayers .playerData").show();

    /* Loop through to check for teams */
    if (teams) {
      teamCols.each(function() {
        if (!this.innerHTML.toUpperCase().includes(teams)) {
          $(this).parent().hide();
        }
      });
    }

    /* Loop and check for min GP */
    GPCols.each(function() {
      if ( Number(this.innerHTML) < minGP) {
        $(this).parent().hide();
      }
    });

    /* Check for age requirement */
    if (age) {
      age = Number(age)
      ageCols.each(function() {
        thisAge = Number(this.innerHTML);
        if ( thisAge < age || thisAge >= age+1 ) {
          $(this).parent().hide();
        }
      });
    }

    /* Check the position requirement */
    if (position) {
      posCols.each(function() {
        var thisPos = this.innerHTML
        if (position == "D") {
          if (thisPos.indexOf("D") == -1) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
          }
        } else if (position == "F") {
          if (thisPos.indexOf("D") != -1) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
          }
        } else if (thisPos != position) {
          $(this).parent().hide();
        }
      });
    }

    autoRank();
}
```

When stripping down the code as minimal as possible, the offending code is the

```
var.each(function() { ...
```

in the `filterTable()` function.

When I run this on Chrome or Firefox it runs quickly (sub 1 second) and the DOM is rendered properly.  When I execute on Safari it takes 30+ seconds.

Why is this and what can I do to adapt for this browser?

---

jQuery: 1.11.1 (same issue even after upgrading to 3.1.1).

Safari: 10.0.1
Firefox: 50
Chrome: 54.0.

Comment: Why you don't try with native JS loop ? It's well known thing that jQuery .each() is slower than native for loop and could be a bottleneck https://jsperf.com/browser-diet-jquery-each-vs-for-loop

Comment: also, this : https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2145 +1 for using vanilla JS

Comment: How is it exponential ? Please don't use the word exponential, it's not even polinomial https://youtu.be/k8lJ3kTT6e8?t=46

Comment: Are you aware that your code has syntax errors (`colGP, colPos, colAge` are undefined)?

Comment: The first thing you should do is paste your code into http://jshint.com/ and fix *all* errors that come up. After that: Scope your variables properly. You are missing `var` keywords all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing all the repetition and unnecessary complication from your code, this is what remains:

```
var colRank = 0, colTeam = 1, colGP = 2, colAge = 3, colPos = 4;

function filterTable() {
    var minGP = +$("#mingp").val();
    var age = +$("#age").val();
    var teams = $("#teamFilter").val().toUpperCase();
    var position = $("#position").val();
    var rank = 0;

    $("#myTablePlayers .playerData").each(function () {
        if (
            (teams && this.cells[colTeam].textContent.toUpperCase().includes(teams)) ||
            (minGP && +this.cells[colGP].textContent < minGP) ||
            (age && (+this.cells[colAge].textContent < age || +this.cells[colAge].textContent >= age+1)) ||
            ((position === "D" || position === "F") && this.cells[colPos].textContent.indexOf(position) === -1) ||
            (!(position === "D" || position === "F") && (this.cells[colPos].textContent !== position))
        ) {
            this.cells[colRank].textContent = ++rank;
            this.style.display = "";
        } else {
            this.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

I've already removed almost all jQuery in favor of native DOM manipulation.

The remaining `.each()` could be tuned into a plain old `for` loop over the `document.getElementById('myTablePlayers').tBodies[0].rows`, if you want to squeeze out the last bit of possible performance.

Reorder the `if` conditions by likeliness: From the one that will typically filter out the most rows to the one that will filter out the least rows. Because JS short-circuits conditions, this way less conditions are checked overall.

Making the [table `display: fixed`](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/) can also improve render performance at the expense of flexibility.

Finally, you can use [CSS to do counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters). This is *probably* faster than manually setting the contents of a table cell. Test for yourself.

Comment: I agree that replacing jQuery by pure JS is a good way to fasten execution. But most of the time it's matter of compromise between performance and code simplicity, so it might be searched only when some points have already been recognized to be critical. In the current case it's different: remember that all works quickly with FF, and the issue appears only with Safari. So I doubt that a simple "general optimization" solves it.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak for your help (And @cFreed) on my previous question.  Swapping to Vanilla JS definitely speeds things up on Safari, with no noticeable difference on FF/Chrome.  So my real world question is answered, but I am curious as to why this is easily 30x slower on Safari vs FF/Chrome (literally 30s+ vs 1 sec).

Comment: I don't know. The only way to find out is to split the task into tiny parts and compare their individual performance. Then combine them in different ways and compare again, etc, until the culprit is found. You can do that if you want.

Comment: Maybe it's one of the string comparisons. Maybe setting the "display" property is slow on Safari.  Maybe the code itself is fast on both browsers but the table re-render is slow on one. There are many possibilities.

Comment: Then I must admit that the thoughts exposed by my previous comment were quite wrong. So I remain very much puzzled: like @ReilyBourne I'm curious to understand _what_ makes the difference. As he said, beyond the solution of his real word issue, it'd be pretty interesting for everybody to identify this "weakness" in the couple Safari/jQuery. Because he's the one who has all the elements for that, I suggest ReilyBourne posts yet another question, now clearly targeted, like "Looking for the cause of the performance difference, on Safari, between these two versions". What do you think about that?

Comment: Out of academic interest I would be curious as well. I'm pretty sure it can be brought down to some known and documented inefficiency in Safari, but identifying that requires resources I don't have – Safari, first and foremost, but also sufficient time.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ill post a question in the next 24 hours when I can sit and document the problem in enough detail.  I appreciate the effort you have put into this.

Comment: @ReilyBourne Thanks for making the effort to extend the tracking of this issue. Like Tomalak, I lack one main resource: Safari (I work on Windows, where it's definitely stuck at the antique 5.1.7). In the other hand I have time available, so I'll interested to follow the case, and exchange to participate in the research. TIA for alerting me with a comment here to announce your new question.