# Why is jQuery's .each drastically slower in Safari than Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is not looking for a solution to a specific problem but trying to understand why Safari is inefficient in this instance.  When I talk about drastically slower, the code runs in Firefox and Chrome in under 1 second while Safari takes in the range of 30-90 seconds. It's likely already a documented issue but I don't know why.

---

The situation is that I have an HTML table that is fairly large.  It's 1,000-1,500 rows by 40 columns wide.  The structure looks something like:

```
<table id="myTablePlayers" class="tablesorter table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="overflow: visible">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>...</th>
          <th>...</th>
          <th>...</th>
          <th>...</th>
          ...
          <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="playerData">
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            ...
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

A number of form fields allow users to select and enter information that help filter out rows.  The jQuery looks like:

```
function autoRank() {
    // auto number
    rank = 0;
    $("#myTablePlayers .playerData").each(function() {
        if ($(this).css("display") != "none") {
            rank++;
            $(this).find('td').eq(colRank).text(rank);
        }
    });
}

function filterTable() {
    // Need some error checking on input not number
    minGP = $("#mingp").val()
    teams = $("#teamFilter").val()
    position = $("#position").val()
    age = $("#age").val()

    $("#myTablePlayers .playerData").show();

    $("#myTablePlayers .playerData").each(function() {
        toHide = false;

        if (teams != "") {
            if ( !$(this).find('td').eq(colTeam).text().toUpperCase().includes(teams.toUpperCase())) {
                toHide = true;
            }
        }

        if ( Number($(this).find('td').eq(colGP).text()) < minGP ) {
            toHide = true;
        }

        if (position != "") {
            if (position == "D") {
                if ($(this).find('td').eq(colPos).text().indexOf("D") == -1) {
                    toHide = true;
                }
            } else if (position == "F") {
                if ($(this).find('td').eq(colPos).text().indexOf("D") != -1) {
                    toHide = true;
                }
            } else if ( $(this).find('td').eq(colPos).text() != position) {
                toHide = true;
            }
        }

        if (age != "") {
            column = Number($(this).find('td').eq(colAge).text())
            age = Number(age)
            if (  column < age || column >= age+1  ) {
                toHide = true;
            }
        }

        if (toHide == true) {
            $(this).hide();
        }

    });

    autoRank();
}

$("#teamFilter").on('change', filterTable);

$("#mingp").on('change', filterTable);

$("#position").on('change', filterTable);

$("#age").on('change', filterTable);
```

When I start pruning down the code, the offending code that takes a long time to run, regardless of what's inside the loop, seems to be `$("#myTablePlayers .playerData").each(function() {...`

I solved the issue by re-writing the code in vanilla JS but that doesn't answer why this code is so inefficient in just one browser.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly not with `.each()` but with that inspection you're doing of the layout via `.css()`.

Comment: Also you really need to be declaring your local variables with `let` or `var`.

Comment: Well thats most probably not the case, but might be a part of it.

Don't do things like $(this) over and over. Because on each call You are wrapping 'this' with jQuery object, and in result You are creating completely new object.

Same goes with selectors. You are querying twice like that $("#myTablePlayers .playerData") so browser has to query Your document twice, and look for these nodes. Thats bad. You should simply cache result of jQuery search into variable.

Comment: @grzesiekgs redundant calls to jQuery are inefficient, but that is completely insignificant compared to making layout inquiries.

Comment: True that, I've missed this little, ugly display check ;)

Comment: When you say *"regardless of what's in the loop"*, does that mean that it's really slow even if the function is empty? `$("#myTablePlayers .playerData").each(function() {})`

Comment: You know, I wonder if there's a recursion issue here. You have `$("#teamFilter").on('change', filterTable);` and a few others, and then in `filterTable`, the `.val()` method is called on the same element(s). I wonder if jQuery is triggering the `change` event internally, which would cause massive recursion.

Comment: ...try changing `$("#teamFilter").val()` to `document.querySelector("#teamFilter").value`, and do the same for the other three as well. If that fixes it, then it's a problem with how jQuery is handling a fix internally in Safari.

Comment: I'd like to remind everyone, this is OP's question `This question is not looking for a solution to a specific problem but trying to understand why Safari is inefficient in this instance`

Comment: @squint I'd be extremely surprised if that were the issue.

Comment: @Pointy: Maybe. Though with a 90 second execution time, some sort of recursion seems like it would be a good possibility. This code isn't terribly efficient, but it's certainly not the least efficient jQuery I've ever seen, and 90 seconds is an eternity.

Comment: Well, the OP is MIA, the example is missing some variables, there's no instruction on exact steps to reproduces, and there's no information on jQuery/Safari versions being used... so I guess there's really not any point in trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 5):

Checking the DOM status by making inquiries via `.css()` can be extremely expensive.
Instead of hiding/revealing elements with `.hide()` and `.show()`, add/remove a class. In your CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Then your `.each()` loop can just check for that class:

```
$("#myTablePlayers .playerData").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("hidden")) {
        rank++;
        $(this).find('td').eq(colRank).text(rank);
    }
});
```

To hide something, you'd just add that class, and to show it you'd remove it:

```
    if (toHide) {
        $(this).addClass("hidden");
    }
```

And to show:

```
$("#myTablePlayers .playerData").removeClass("hidden");
```

Now, all those `.find()` and `.text()` calls are going to be expensive too. It would probably be worthwhile to initialize the table by going over it once and creating data properties on each `<tr>` to effectively cache the interesting values from each row. Lookups via jQuery's `.data()` will be significantly cheaper than looking by selector in the DOM (though modern DOM implementations are pretty fast).

Comment: `if (toHide == true) {` should be `if (toHide) {` (unless you're worried that someone has `var toHide = new Boolean(false);` somewhere)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yes, true; I just copy/pasted but I'll fix it.

Comment: Consider rolling the class check into the selector too: `$("#myTablePlayers .playerData:not(.hidden)")`.

Comment: @squint that's not a bad idea, but I'm not 100% sure it'd actually be faster. If `querySelectorAll()` can deal with the `:not()` then probably it is, but if jQuery has to use Sizzle then maybe not.

Comment: The `:not()` is definitely `qSA` compliant *as long as* you have a single simple selector. So no groups, no combinators and no sequences of more than one simple selector. So `.hidden` will meet that criteria. But I agree with the sentiment of keeping selectors standards compliant.

Comment: @squint that's good to know :) I'm never 100% sure about anything, basically.

Comment: @Pointy One could use `$("#myTablePlayers .playerData").not(".hidden");` which will be faster than `$("#myTablePlayers .playerData:not(.hidden)")`, if Sizzle ends interpreting it.

Comment: @squint honestly all those `.find()` and `.text()` calls are going to be expensive too. I'm going to extend the answer again.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that the `.eq()` is using `colRank`. When I glanced at it at first, I thought it was using `rank`, which seemed really odd. So yeah, you can probably squeeze a bit more into that selector. `$("#myTablePlayers .playerData:not(.hidden) td:nth-child(" + (colRank+1) + ")").text(function(td) { return ++rank })` ... or something.

Comment: Considering how long the function is taking for the OP to execute, I think the issue is elsewhere. I believe it's related to a long or infinite recursion caused internally, stemming from the `change` event. See my last comment below the question.

Comment: The op is also mostly concerned about why this issue is presented 80x worse in Safari. If it were truly just expensive for `.css` then every browser would be having the issue.

Comment: @christopherclark not every browser implements DOM APIs the same way. The implementation of `.each()` is what will be the same in every browser; it's very simple.

Comment: @Pointy `This question is not looking for a solution to a specific problem but trying to understand why Safari is inefficient in this instance`

Comment: @christopherclark the code posted is inefficient in **all** browsers, but it's more obvious in some.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it was the CSS `.hide()` or `.show()`.  The working solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870513/jquerys-each-slower-on-safari-than-chrome-firefox) has `this.style.display = "none";` which helps.  I don't think it's a recursive call because the `.on("change"...` applies only to input/select items outside the table.  Everyone has great suggestions here, but they are all answering a specific question, not my question: "why is Safari specifically bad at this?"

Comment: @ReilyBourne well to figure out the Safari issue it'd take some profiling on Safari. *Something* is slower on Safari, clearly, but it could be a variety of things. Personally I'm pretty confident that the JavaScript code behind the `.each()` method is *not* likely to be the culprit.

Comment: One of my experiments had the `.each` method only contain a `console.log()` and that was still experiencing similar slow times.

Comment: Again, I'd much more readily blame `console.log()` than I would the very simple JavaScript code behind `.each()`. You might want to look at jsperf.com.