# How can I use scrollIntoView() under jQuery syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to do let the last reply scroll into view using jQuery. Here is my code:

```
function showHideReplies(replies){
 replies.each(function() {
     if($(this).index() < nIniRep || afterReply){
            $(this).show();
            if(afterReply && $(this).index()==replies.length ){
                $(this).scrollIntoView();
            }
        }else{
            $(this).hide();
        }

 });
```

}

`afterReply` was defined in my JavaScript.

My question is: I know `scrollIntoView()` is an HTML DOM Method, and you can use it like this:

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

But I need to use with jQuery, and I think it should work the same way. But it doesn't work with the jQuery syntax `$(this).scrollIntoView();`

How do I use `scrollIntoView()` under jQuery syntax?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not simply do `this.scrollIntoView()`? Also, it may be worth [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743326/why-cache-jquery-objects) `$(this)` into a variable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

jQuery's `$(this)` returns a [**jQuery object**](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). To target this element itself, you need to access the first index of the object with `[0]`. Essentially, jQuery's `$(this)[0]` is equivalent to JavaScript's `this`.

As such, you're looking for:

```
$(this)[0].scrollIntoView();
```

Hope this helps! :)