# reset height set by function on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a two column layout, where every block has a different height according to the content inside it. I wrote some jquery lines that take every pair of blocks, and apply the greater of both heights to both blocks, and it works fine, but I need it to resize on windows resize, and I'm stuck on how to do this.

I tried wrapping the function in a window.resize event but that didn't work at all. Once the page loads and the function runs one time, the heights don't change any more, so if I resize the window the content overflows.

The html code of the layout:

```html
 <div class="catmenu cat61">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row itemenu par">
              <p>content</p><p>content</p>
            </div>
            <hr class="hrp">
            <div class="row itemenu par">
               <p>content</p><p>content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row itemenu impar">
              <p>longer</p><p>content</p><p>longer</p><p>content</p>
            </div>
            <hr class="hrp">
            <div class="row itemenu impar">
               <p>longer</p><p>content</p><p>longer</p><p>content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery that does the trick on load:

```js
 
var height1 = Math.max($( ".cat61 > div > div .row.itemenu.impar:nth-child(1)" ).height(), $( ".cat61 > div > div .row.itemenu.par:nth-child(1)" ).height());
 $(".cat61 > div > div .row.itemenu.impar:nth-child(1), .cat61 > div > div .row.itemenu.par:nth-child(1)").height(height1);
```

I need the function to run on window.resize and update the heights according to the auto heights the blocks would render on resize, I'm guessing I need to somehow apply the auto height first and then run the jquery again but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried `<body onresize="function()">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right idea with using the `window.resize` event. I suspect that you were running into the problem that, once the `height` values are set on page load, subsequent `.height()` attempts will return that first derived `height1` value.

Another issue might have been that you were caching `height1` only on page load, so using it as-is (i.e. not recalculating it afresh) on `resize` will only ever set the heights to that first value.

If you create a method for your resizing that both clears any previously set `height` values **and** recalculates the "natural" heights of the elements, it should work to dynamically maintain the row heights the way you're expecting.

```
function reset_heights() {

  // CLEAR the last, programmatically set, height values (or they will never change)
  $(".cat61 > div > div .row.itemenu.impar:nth-child(1), .cat61 > div > div .row.itemenu.par:nth-child(1)").height( '' );

  // THEN measure their "natural" heights
  var height1 = Math.max( $( ".cat61 > div > div .row.itemenu.impar:nth-child(1)" ).height(), $( ".cat61 > div > div .row.itemenu.par:nth-child(1)" ).height());

  // THEN set the newly derived max height
  $(".cat61 > div > div .row.itemenu.impar:nth-child(1), .cat61 > div > div .row.itemenu.par:nth-child(1)").height( height1 ); 
}

// set your `resize` listener/handler
$( window ).on( 'resize', function ( event ) {
  reset_heights();
} );

// do your initial page-load resizing
reset_heights();
```

That said, `resize` fires **a lot**. So that `resize` event handler can be "expensive", processing-wise. I'd recommend that you leverage a bit of [jQuery Object caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23743458/5796134), and maybe consider [debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24004791/5796134).